# How to format JSON for Volley Put request for Mapbox API

Tags: android, json, android-volley, mapbox, mapbox-marker

I swear I have exhausted my search on this and have been working for 2 days. I'm attempting to use a Volley Put Request which contains a JSON object and embedded Array.

I'm working from the example from the Mapbox API: https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#insert-or-update-a-feature

What I need to send:

```html
curl "https://api.mapbox.com/datasets/v1/therefore/lkjashdglkhasdkljsa/features/test123456?dfalkjhsfdlkjhdfs" \
  -X PUT \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d @file.geojson

{
  "id": "test123456",
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [ 100, 0 ],
        [ 101, 0 ],
        [ 101, 1 ],
        [ 100, 1 ],
        [ 100, 0 ]
      ]
    ]
  },
  "properties": {
    "prop0": "value0"
  }
}
```

The code I have working so far is able to post a new dataset to the server, but my intentions are to put a new point feature on the map. Here is my creation...

//This creates a new dataset on the server
    public void postMethod(View view) {

```
    final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, postdatapointurl,
            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response).getJSONObject("form");
                        String site = jsonResponse.getString("site"),
                                network = jsonResponse.getString("network");
                        System.out.println("Site: "+site+"\nNetwork: "+network);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    textview.setText(response);
                    requestQueue.stop();
                }
            }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            textview.setText("something went wrong");
            error.printStackTrace();
            requestQueue.stop();
        }
    })

    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("id","nate123456789");
            params.put("geometry",{"type","Polygon") // <-- obviously wrong. This is where the problem is.
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/application.json");
            //headers.put("", "value");
            return headers;
        }
    };
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);


}
```

Getting the JSON formatted correctly and setting the PUT up right would be so helpful. I have really tried my brain out. Thanks.

Comment: Obviously you should use jsonrequest instead StringRequest

Answer (score 0):

We have support for GeoJSON objects in the [Mapbox Android Services](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/#mapbox_android_services) library. With it, you can create a `Feature` object programmatically (e.g. `Feature.fromGeometry(Geometry geometry)`), or from a raw `geojson` string (to parse the server response):

`Feature geo = Feature.fromJson(geojson);
assertEquals(geo.getType(), "Feature");
assertEquals(geo.getGeometry().getType(), "Point");`

Unfortunately, we still don't support the Datasets API but we're tracking its implementation on https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/issues/101.

Comment: Thank you so much for commenting. I have completed the tutorial, have a map on my app, can POST a new dataset, and GET all of my features on a map into a text window, but the goal of my project is to add a feature to a dataset on the mapbox servers. Is this currently possible with the method you are mentioning?